# Iterating through columns and array

Tags: python

In python I'm trying to loop through two columns and an array at at the same time. I was playing with the zip function but without success.

```
a=np.array(range(1,21))
b=np.array(range(4,24))
#DATA#####
i=a.reshape(4,5)
v=b.reshape(4,5)
temp=np.array(range(1,5))
```

I have three input parameters for my function i,v and temp, every time I want to run the function I need to change the i,v and temp manually. Now I want to build a loop that will return me the columns of I and V and the values of temp.
In the first itteration my input needs to be the following:

```
i=1,2,3,4,5
v=4,5,6,7,8
temp=1
```

in the second itteration

```
i=6,7,8,9,10
v=9,10,11,12,13
temp=2
```

and so on

Not sure how to combine columns and array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in many ways, e.g.:

```
for j in range(len(temp)):
    par0 = i[j]
    par1 = v [j]
    par2 = temp[j]
    # to check the output
    print('Iteration:', j, '\ni=', par0, '\nv=', par1, '\ntemp=', par2)
```

or

```
for j,par2 in enumerate(temp):
    par0 = i[j]
    par1 = v [j]
    # to check the output
    print('Iteration:', j, '\ni=', par0, '\nv=', par1, '\ntemp=', par2)
```

If you need a tuple like in your example you can recast the parameters with `tuple(parameter)`.